# Drawing smooth circle

Tags: opengl, opentk

I'm using OpenTK (C#) but OpenGL suggestions are welcome too.

I have a point list generated by iteration having 1 degrees per point around the center point which means there are 361 point including the center point. Point list can be different with different approaches, that's ok. I can draw the circle with the below simple Vertex and Fragment shaders. How can change the fragment and/or vertex shaders to have a smooth circle.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330
in  vec3 vPosition;
in  vec4 vColor;
out vec4 color;
out vec4 fPosition;
uniform mat4 modelview;
void main()
{
    fPosition = modelview * vec4(vPosition, 1.0);
    gl_Position = fPosition;
    color = vColor;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330
in vec4 color;
in vec4 fPosition;
out vec4 outputColor;
void main()
{
    outputColor = color;
}
```

C# code:

```
GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.TriangleFan, 0, points.Length);
```

Comment: Come on @genpfault you just deleted my final word from original post? why don't you give me a solution? I'm new to OpenGL..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello what do you actually see ? Post a screenshot. Anyway for smooth edges we have what's called anti alising.
Use this line for your glControl to enable it

```
glControl = new GLControl(new OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsMode(32, 24, 0, 8));
```

Comment: Thank @tomer zeitune, that worked. There is also a smoothstep usage in GLSL that I couldn't figure out for my circles. But this is good. I'm using GLControl in WPF within WindowsFormsHost element to create a XAML user control. In XAML I couldn't set the GraphicsMode of GLControl but I created another class inheriting GLControl like below and it worked:

`public class AAGLControl : GLControl
    {
        public AAGLControl()
            : base (new OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsMode(32, 24, 0, 8))
        {
        }
    }`